# Properties of the graph of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$X$ be a compact topo space, $f$ is a real valued function on $X$, Then $$G_f=\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}\subseteq X\times\mathbb{R}$$

$1.$ $G_f$ is closed iff $f$ is continuous

$2.$ $G_f$ is closed if $f$ is continuous

$3.$ if $f$ is bounded continuous function then $G_f$ is compact.

$4$. if $f$ is continuous then $G_f$ is connected.

$4$ is false as $X$ was not said that it is connected, $2$ is true by sequential criterion of continuity we can show that if $f$ is continuous function then its graph is closed, I have no idea or counter example whether the converse is true or false, please help. and about $3$, I am sure it is true as $X$ is compact so image of it under continuous map will be compact but I don't know why boundedness condition is given here.

Comment: See this. It may be helpful for you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338745/a-question-on-a-continuous-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=I$, the unit interval with the topology inherited by $\Bbb R$.
Let $f:I\to\Bbb R,\\
f(x)=\cases{
0&\text{, if } x=0\\
1/x&\text{, if } x>0
}$

The graph is closed in $(0,1]\times\mathbb R$ by $2$) since $f$ is continuous there. It is easy to show that it is also closed in $I\times\mathbb R$.

There is also another way to show closedness of $G_f$ if you know that the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x)\mid x\in Y\}$ is closed if $Y$ is Hausdorff.

As for $3$), you are right that boundedness is unnecessary, because $f$ maps the compact $X$ to a compact image.

You are also right that the graph need not be connected since $X$ is not connected. You could ask yourself what happens **if** $X$ is connected.